# Selenium Python - How to get class id by clicking on it manually

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button on a page that has a lot of JavaScript but no matter what I try, can't click it. Is there a way for me to click the button manually and get what I need to click?

I've tried inspecting elements and FirePath but those aren't giving me the correct class or id that I need to click

Edit: This is what I'm trying to accomplish, the below is from Selenium IDE firefox plugin

```
Command                   Target
open                /logger/summary.ftl
clickAndWait        link=System Admin
selectFrame         sysadmin-content
click               //div[@id='sysadminmenu__sysadminmenu_x-auto-29']/span[3]/span
click              id=x-auto-178
```

Comment: Posting some code or an example of your issue will lead to better answers.

Comment: Added the Selenium IDE plugin commands

Answer (score 0):

You may try 
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

This has a feature to find web element path